# Parse-server on DigitalOcean - Error 502

Tags: parse-platform, nginx, digital-ocean

I've followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

All fine, except that when it comes to sending a POST request to the Parse-server, I get an error 502. Here are both POST and GET requests which return a 502 when using https and a 301 when using HTTP:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppId" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sammy","cheatMode":false}' \
https://domain.name/parse/classes/GameScore

curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPID" http://domain.name/parse/classes/GameScore
```

I specially wanted to check if

> mongod.conf

is fine (mine is the same as the one on the tutorial) and if

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

is also fine.

Here is the log:

```
2016/03/07 22:11:30 [error] 7288#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: myComputerIP, server: domain.name, request: "GET /parse/classes/GameScore HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/classes/GameScore", host: "domain.name"
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your node.js server isn't running (or not listening on port 1337) - make sure it's up by running and if not, start the `parse-server`.

Comment: I've tried manually starting parse-server but it doesn't help. My server is listening on 0.0.0.0. I've also allowed port 1337 on the firewall. Still won't work.

Comment: is the server listening on port 1773? What does `sudo netstat -plane | grep LISTEN | grep 1337` say?

Comment: I think you've hit it. This returns nothing so I suppose node isn't listening on 1337 (or parse-server isn't running). The tutorial uses pm2 to install parse-server and I don't know where to find its folder in order to check if the port is rightfully set. This is progress but I am still stuck.

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/syslog` returns: 
`Mar 12 07:17:01 Parse CRON[17623]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 12 08:17:01 Parse CRON[10044]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 12 09:17:01 Parse CRON[2604]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

Comment: eh, is there a parse-server specific log file? maybe in `/var/log/parse-server` or so?

Comment: I couldn't find a log for parse-server but the tutorial installs parse-server via pm2, and here is the pm2 log: http://pastebin.com/z1i2ZXP9
It seems parse-server gets shut down as soon as it launches?

Comment: See this error? `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

Comment: Maybe your config is broken?

Comment: I've check over all the files I've edited and I haven't found a single syntax error. I can't promise it's not broken but I don't know what else i can do.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, in my case was an error due to the change of the path of an internal dependency during the migration. 
I was able to troubleshoot it using:

`pm2 logs 0`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep. I end up with the log I posted below (http://pastebin.com/z1i2ZXP9). I've gone through my config files and I have no idea what's wrong. I've configured everything by the book and checked the syntax of the files I've edited. All looks good but yet it won't work.

Comment: Also it would be good if you could clarify "Path of the code". What are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for amending. It would be interesting to know what dependancy caused an issue and how you fixed it. I am still stuck after 2 weeks. The logs don't show a file I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

There was a syntax error in my cloud code.